# Ruby - Form doesn't submit to the right page in Selenium-Webdriver

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium-webdriver

I am attempting to write some automated tests for a client my company has been working for. One of these tests is to have Selenium-WebDriver enter a username and password and login. When I do that manually as a human user, I get redirected to the right page (the base url page) and get logged in successfully. However, if I have Selenium-WebDriver do it, the page gets redirected to /users/:id and a 404 error occurs.

I have pasted the code in its most basic form below. I think the issue is due to page redirects but I can't be sure. (This is a rails project, the automated test is external.) I have tried adding delays, I've tried adding waits, and I've even tried slowing WebDriver down to solve this issue. Nothing seems to work. I don't know how to add a wait directly into the click function of the submit button. If anyone has any further ideas, that would be great.

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
driver.navigate.to ''
driver.find_element(:id, 'user_email').send_keys ''
driver.find_element(:id, 'user_password').send_keys ''
driver.find_element(:name, 'commit').click
sleep 5 # this is so my eyes have time to see if it worked
driver.quit
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're probably clicking the wrong button, there might be more of them with a name "commit". If you can share me the page, I would tell you more.

Comment: Good thought. Unfortunately, I already checked that and there is only one. You can view the page source if you'd like. I checked by viewing that and loading an array of all tags with the name "commit."

Comment: When I use the credentials in your code manually, I am redirected to https://sgstoolwizard.com/users/1 and I get the message, "The page you were looking for doesn't exist.

You may have mistyped the address or the page may have moved.

If you are the application owner check the logs for more information." Looks like something is just wrong with the login page or the credentials are bad.

Comment: BTW, if you want to see if it worked, remove the last line, `driver.quit`. :)

Comment: It's just that it works when done manually but not when done through automation. That's why I'm confused.

Comment: Good call, @JeffC. :)

Comment: I'm saying I can't get it to work manually using the credentials you have in your code above.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's a browser thing. It works in some browsers, but not others.

Thank you for your thoughts!